# \newcommand in the MediaWiki Math extension

Tags: mediawiki, latex, mediawiki-extensions

When using the [MediaWiki MathJax extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aMathJax), it's trivial to create new commands with \newcommand.  From the MathJax documentation:

> You can use the \def, \newcommand, \renewcommand, \newenvironment, \renewenvironment, and \let commands to create your own macros and environments. Unlike actual TeX, however, in order for MathJax to process these, they must be enclosed in math delimiters (since MathJax only processes macros in math-mode).

LaTeX command implementation in MathJax is somewhat limited, so I am also evaluating the [MediaWiki Math extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aMath).  The \newcommand syntax doesn't appear to work here, and I get a **failed to parse unknown function** error.

Is it possible to define new macros in the MediaWiki Math extension?  If so, how?